# Modifying html element created in jQuery, inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem:** I can't modify an HTML element I created inside a function.

**Code:**

I read I can create an element from a string this way.

```
var base_html = $("<div id='base'><div id='chart_container_bars'></div>"+
                      "<br>"+
                      "<br>"+
                      "<div id='chart_container_lines'></div>"+
                      "<table class='table table-bordered' id='tabla_servicios' style='width:100%; padding:12px'>"+
                      "</table>"+
                    "</div>");
```

So I assumed I could use selectors to modify that piece of HTML code like this.

```
var tabla_servicios = base_html.find($("#tabla_servicios"));
tabla_servicios.html("<p>HI</p>");
```

And then get the HTML back to a string with:

```
var html_str = base_html.html();
```

But I haven't been able to do it.

**Desired result**:

```
var final_html_str = $("<div id='base'><div id='chart_container_bars'></div>"+
                      "<br>"+
                      "<br>"+
                      "<div id='chart_container_lines'></div>"+
                      "<table class='table table-bordered' id='tabla_servicios' style='width:100%; padding:12px'>"+
                      "<p>HI</p>"+
                      "</table>"+
                    "</div>");
```

**Question**:

Is there a way to create an HTML element from a string and modify it with selectors afterwards?

Comment: Try `jQuery.parseHTML()` instead of `$`.

Comment: Instead of selecting the id and then using find with the selected element just pass the id directly to the find: https://jsfiddle.net/b3Lqj3ka/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jquery find function you have to pass the selector as a string.

```js
var base_html = $("<div id='base'><div id='chart_container_bars'></div>"+
                      "<br>"+
                      "<br>"+
                      "<div id='chart_container_lines'></div>"+
                      "<table id='tabla_servicios' class='table table-bordered' id='tabla_servicios' style='width:100%; padding:12px'>"+
                      "</table>"+
                    "</div>");

var tabla_servicios = base_html.find("#tabla_servicios");
tabla_servicios.html("<p>HI</p>");

var html_str = base_html.html();

console.log(html_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```